# Control extension on upload file PHP

Tags: php, file

I have tested this for control and accept only jpg and pdf but it doesn't run

```
$nomedic = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$extdic = pathinfo($nomedic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($extdic != "pdf" OR $extdic != "jpg" OR $extdic != "jpeg")
{
    header('Location:fileko.php');
}


$finedic='DIC';
$nomedichiarazione=$id_ope.'-'.$id_dom.'-'.$prot_dom.'-'.$A016.'-'.$finedic.'.'.$extdic;
```

Comment: _"but dont run"_ means what exactly?

Comment: you can try doing it at input type="file"  level itself , no need to include php. You can do it like <input type="file" accept="image/*,.pdf">

Comment: your logic is wrong, it will always evaluate to true, even if the extension is "pdf". Make it the other way round: if pdf or jpg -> pass, else header redirect

Comment: @Satya You should *always* verify server-side that the data you get is what you expect. That check can be easily removed, and then I can upload `.gif` :-) You can do *both*, but *always* on the server.

Comment: got it Qirel , thanks a lot for the tip. WIll keep this in mind next time.

Comment: @Qirel instead of OR use And the logic will work then...

Comment: You also might want to use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php in case a file has an uppercase extension ('test.PDF')

Answer (score 0):

PHP will check each condition until it finds something that is `true`. This means that even if your file is a PDF-file, the `$extdic != "jpg"` condition will trigger and return true, thereby running the header-call.

You can create an array of all allowed extensions, and check if the current file's extension exists in that list. If it doesn't, redirect away! You should also call `exit;` after a `header("Location: ..");` call.

I've also added `strtolower()`, in case the incoming file has an uppercase extension (e.g. `myFile.JPG`).

```
if(!in_array(strtolower($extdic), ["pdf", "jpg", "jpeg"])) {
    header('Location:fileko.php');
    exit;
}
```